# CROSS JOIN with USING?

Tags: sql

Working on a [javascript SQL parser](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/) I am testing against the [sqllogic test that SQLite also uses](http://www.sqlite.org/sqllogictest/doc/trunk/about.wiki) to verify the logic.

I came across this SQL and cant figure out how to treat it.

```
SELECT ALL * FROM tab1 cor0 CROSS JOIN tab1 USING col1, col2, tab2 AS cor1;
```

As I understand the `CROSS JOIN` joins **all** rows in two tables - so i guess the `USING` part have no effect?

#### Is my conclusion correct?: For a coss join one can disregard the `USING` part?

Comment: Is that valid syntax in any DBMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a weirdism of SQLite (and perhaps MySQL).  `CROSS JOIN` should be producing a Cartesian product and it should not be taking a `USING` or `ON` clause.

However, the SQLite syntax allows an `ON` or `USING` clause with `CROSS JOIN`.  In that case, it behaves like an `INNER JOIN`.

Also, SQLite allows you to leave off the `ON`/`USING`clauses for other types of join.  In that case, these behave like a `CROSS JOIN`.

My recommendation:  do not learn this syntax (which is highly non-standard).  Using the following rules:

- *Always* use `ON`/`USING` with inner and outer joins.
- *Never* use `ON`/`USING` with `CROSS JOIN`.
- Avoid `NATURAL JOIN`.  Because this does not list the `JOIN` keys, the code is much less maintainable, susceptible to subtle errors, and can change meaning if the underlying tables change.